# can't generate show path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a controller:

```
class Admin::MassScanListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @mass_scan_lists = MassScanList.all
  end

  def show

  end
end
```

an appropriate simple model `MassScanList` and a view, where I want to list all my MassScanLists with links to show their content:

```
- if @mass_scan_lists.present?  
  - @mass_scan_lists.each do |list|
    tr
      td= list.id
      td= link_to list.name, list
      td= list.enabled
```

I get an error `undefined method 'mass_scan_list_path'` which is I suppose I can understand, it must be `admin_mass_scan_list_path`, because my controller is `Admin::MassScanListsController` and not `MassScanListsController`. Bot how can I generate a show path in my case?

P.S.
In my `routes.rb` I have:

```
constraints admins_constraint do
  namespace 'admin' do
    resources :mass_scan_lists, only: [:index, :show]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
link_to list.name, admin_mass_scan_list_path(list)
```